# Angular 4 component extends/inheritance

Tags: javascript, angular

I am trying to create an Angular 4 component that holds the style and markup for a generic box which could be extended with custom behavior/content.

So far I have a basic component that implements an interface like this:

```
export interface Box {
  heading: string;
  icon: string;
  myEventHandler();
}


@Component({
  selector: 'my-box',
  templateUrl: './box.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./box.component.scss'],
})
export class BoxComponent implements Box {
  public heading: string;
  public icon: string;
  public myEventHandler(){};
}

// box.component.html
<div class="generic-box">
  <header>
    <i class="{{icon}}"></i>
    <h4>{{heading}}</h4>
    <a class="btn btn-primary" (click)="myEventHandler($ev)">
      Btn goes here
    </a>
  </header>

  <div class="box-content">
    <ng-content></ng-content>
  </div>

</div>
```

^box.component.html

And a custom component that needs to be an implementation of that BoxComponent with some custom behavior/content:

```
<my-box>
  <p>Content</p>
</my-box>
```

^custom-box.component.html

```
@Component({
  selector: 'custom-box',
  templateUrl: './custom-box.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./custom-box.component.scss']
})
export class CustomBox extends BoxComponent {
  heading = 'Custom heading';
  icon = 'icon-name';
  myEventHandler() {
    console.log('bar');
  }
}
```

I have also attached a sketch for a better understanding how Box Component template looks.

What is the correct approach to extend the BoxComponent? Is this the Angular way? If the answer is yes, what do I miss since it is not working?

[image]

Comment: You're not really making full use of the component model here. Pass in `heading` and `icon` using `@Input()`, and make `myEventHandler` an `@Output()`.

Comment: Ok, makes sense. Do you recommend this way of component inheritance or is something else better?

Comment: You should almost always use inputs, outputs and `ng-content` to make reusable components rather than subclassing, in my opinion. The only situation where I would consider using inheritance would be if I wasn't able to modify the original component (e.g. customising something from a library).

Comment: That's fine. Actually i wanted to extend the decorators, to be able to use the same template everywhere.